# "Invalid captcha" always happening in Wordpress Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I just added recaptcha to a contact form I have in a Wordpress site. I followed the steps here:

[How to add recaptcha](https://contactform7.com/recaptcha/)

So I created my recaptcha pair **sitekey-secretkey** and now they are configured in my Wordpress site as said in this manual.

I also added this div:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekey"></div>
```

But when I use the captcha, it always says "**Invalid captcha**". Why is this happening? I followed all steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when migrating to a new server but with differenct contact form plugin.

I found [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-solve-the-recaptcha-to-continue/) which says:

```
 allow_url_fopen setting was not properly “on”
```

Unfortunately, that was already on in my case, so I was  unable to fix the issue. Maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to [Google’s reCAPTCHA admin page.](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list)
2. Register your site.
3. Get a site key and secret key.

Copy the key pair into the WordPress admin screen of the site you registered.

1. Go to the admin menu Contact > Integration.
2. Find reCAPTCHA panel and click Configure Keys.
3. Copy the site key and secret key into the fields and save them.

For more information follow this link : https://contactform7.com/recaptcha/

Comment: That's what the link I posted says and I just made... That didn't work!